# Need To Authonticate User Via Facebook & Twitter(PhonegapAndroid)

Tags: android, html, facebook-graph-api, cordova, twitter-oauth

new to phonegap programing development.having one issue that i need to authonticate user via facebook/twitter & if authontication goes true on basis of that need to upload some image to server..i have stuck on this issue..i could found this one facebook sdk for phonegap android.i have downloaded this one plugin https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect  but when implemented it just redirects to facebook page to browser,it dosen't opening popup of facebook login page as we can see in native android application...so any guide for that?
Thanks in advance 
Aamirkhan i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've recently developed an iOS phonegap app.  We had to pull a feed from Twitter (to our Grails server component) and elected to use Twitter4J as it simplified the process.  Here's a [code example](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth) on the Twitter4J site focussed particularly on authentication.  Hope it helps.  Good luck!

Comment: entire Code is looiking like java class,can u tell me how can i apply it on phonegap?,& it will be better if u can give me sample code u have built..

Comment: Does your phonegap app have a server component i.e. an app server that it pulls content down from?  That's normally how you set a phonegap app up AFAIK.  Then, when the end user logs in using their Twitter credentials, you post them to your server and authenticate them using the API.  If your server component is done in some other technology, there is likely a client library for it.  See here, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries.

Answer (score 0):

When you get redirected to the web page instead of the popup it means that the facebook app is not installed on your phone. This is unfortunately necessary now with the new FB jar.